# How to use a listener in an background service in Flutter (for Android)?

Tags: android, flutter, background-process

I want to create a background service in Flutter that stays active even when the app is not in the foreground or gets killed. This service should contain a listener that returns a value every time a specific event happens, so the app can handle it (by for example saving the current state inside a shared preference). What is the best way to achieve this? **Thanks a lot for any help!**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, it turned out to be harder than I thought I would. You have to learn about Flutters way to talk the native code. You will need to implement background services natively and use if from Flutter with MethodChannels.

This is Flutter's doc about Background processes: [Background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) - which leads to great article that covers what you want and does an example project: [Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).

Good luck!